# Change constraint second item

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

[image]

I have a view with this constraint. I want to animate it and move to bottom of `NavigationBar`. So i want to change `Second item` attribute to something like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(15.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
    if (self.isViewLoaded() && self.view.window != nil) {
         //How to set bottom item ?
         self.storeSelectViewVerticalContainerConstraint.secondItem = self.navigationController?.view.bottom
         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}, completion: {(Bool) in})
```

This code returns error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'secondItem' is a get-only property

Or if this method is impossible, how to calculate, and move object from middle to top of view with navigation bar.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could add a second constraint with lower priority to start and then update both priorities when you need to:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(15.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
    if (self.isViewLoaded() && self.view.window != nil) {
         self.storeSelectViewVerticalContainerConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
         self.storeSelectViewTopContainerConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh
         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}, completion: {(Bool) in})
```

Remember to not move the priority from required to not required though, since [that's not allowed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/priority). But moving from an optional value to another optional value is ok.

Alternatively you could just remove/add these constraints instead of changing their priority.

Comment: Are you sure that moving from a required priority to a high or less priority is not allowed if there is still at least one required? I didn't find where it was written on the link you gave. Good solution btw.

Answer (score 2):

Here Second Item is UIView(Main Root View), which is Y Axis Fixed. It can't be altered.

If you want animation of store selection view, you should change its constant from one value to another, and do

```
storeSelectViewVerticalContainerConstraint.constant = 0; // or any value you want.
UIView.animateWithDuration(5) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Thanks. 
Happy Coding!